# Where to get the activity I'm currently in?

Tags: android, android-activity, java-native-interface

Here's my case
1. start main and the only activity of my app, the activity is almost empty at the startup moment
2. bind to a local service, which is nearly a wrapper of my legacy native library
3. all views will be dynamically created during runtime
4. it's service who determines when and how to build views, of course, mostly in native C++ code and JNI calls

So, I'm required to get a Context, actually current activity, since every constructor of Views requires a Context as a parameter. But how can I get the Context and cache it, if possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind to the service in your activity and pass a context in some method like

```
service.setActivityContext(this);
```

Comment: Service has to save it as static, and then native code could access it by GetObjectField, am I right? Is there another way to dynamically get it instead of being a static filed?

Comment: Why you think it should be static? It should not. GetObjectField can access non-static fields too.